# Resize an image in word

Tags: excel, delphi, ms-word

I am after resizing an image that is placed into word from the clipboard. It was a chart that was copied from excel. This is the current code that i have of the copy and paste

```
    Procedure CopyChartToWord(Place:String);
    var
      Sheets: Variant;
    begin
      Sheets := XLApp.Sheets;
      Sheets.Item['Chart1'].Select;
      XLApp.Selection.Copy;
      wrdApp.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToBookmark,emptyParam,emptyParam,Place);
      wrdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat(wdChartPicture);
    End;
```

i am struggling to find how to resize and possibly crop the image so that it will fit how i want it to on the page. Variable Place is a bookmark within the template for the word document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the secret to automating just about anything in Office? Record a macro in Word where you manually perform whatever it is you want to do. Then, look at the VBA code Word generates for you, and write the corresponding code in the language you're using for your automation.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I was not actually familiar with this as i don't often work with office in this way